# Ajustando saida de dados em C

Tags: c

Gostaria que a saida mostrasse a tabuada de cada operação de lado a lado, e não uma embaixo da outra(que é a forma que ta imprimindo). Eis o codigo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{

  int i, num, rsoma, rsubtracao, rmultiplicacao;
  float rdivisao;

  i = 1;
  printf("Informe um numero inteiro: \n");
  scanf("%i", &num);
  printf("Adição\n\n");

  for ( i = 1; i < 11; i++)
  {
    rsoma = num + i;
    printf("%i + %i = %i\n", num, i, rsoma);
  }

  printf("\nSubtração\n\n");
  for ( i = 1; i < 11; i++)
  {
    rsubtracao = num - i;
    printf("%i - %i = %i\n", num, i, rsubtracao);
  }

  printf("\nMultiplicacao\n\n");
  for ( i = 1; i < 11; i++)
  {
    rmultiplicacao = num * i;
    printf("%i x %i = %i\n", num, i, rmultiplicacao);
  }

  printf("\nDivisao\n\n");
  for ( i = 1; i < 11; i++)
  {
    rdivisao = (float)num / i;
    printf("%i / %i = %.2f\n", num, i, rdivisao);
  }

 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Substitua este \n (nova linha) do printf por um \t (tabulação).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segue um exemplo conforme solicitado, utilizando `\t` (tabs):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    int i, num, rsoma, rsubtracao, rmultiplicacao;
    float rdivisao;

    i = 1;
    printf("Informe um numero inteiro: \n");
    scanf("%i", &num);
    printf("Adição\t\tSubtração\t\tMultiplicação\t\tDivisão\n\n");

    for ( i = 1; i < 11; i++)
    {
        rsoma = num + i;
        rsubtracao = num - i;
        rmultiplicacao = num * i;
        rdivisao = (float)num / i;
        printf("%i + %i = %i\t%i - %i = %i\t\t%i x %i = %i\t\t%i / %i = %.2f\n", num, i, rsoma, num, i, rsubtracao, num, i, rmultiplicacao, num, i, rdivisao);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seria algo desse tipo, em C é complicado poder dar um "float" na resposta, porem a solucao é essa
 #include 
    #include 
    #include

```
int main()
{

  int i, num, rsoma, rsubtracao, rmultiplicacao;
  float rdivisao;

  i = 1;
  printf("Informe um numero inteiro: \n");
  scanf("%i", &num);
  printf("Adição\n\n");

  for ( i = 1; i < 11; i++)
  {
    rsoma = num + i;
    printf("%i + %i = %i\n", num, i, rsoma);
  }

  printf("\nSubtração\n\n");
  for ( i = 1; i < 11; i++)
  {
    rsubtracao = num - i;
    printf("%i - %i = %i\n", num, i, rsubtracao);
  }

  printf("\tMultiplicacao\n\n");
  for ( i = 1; i < 11; i++)
  {
    rmultiplicacao = num * i;
    printf("\t %i x %i = %i\n", num, i, rmultiplicacao);
  }

  printf("\t Divisao\n\n");
  for ( i = 1; i < 11; i++)
  {
    rdivisao = (float)num / i;
    printf("%i / %i = %.2f\n", num, i, rdivisao);
  }

 return 0;
}
```